# Get an array with DomainObjects in a single Extbase ControllerAction argument

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I'm creating an extbase extension to handle very simple product orders.
The model is:

```
Order --1:n--> OrderItem --1:1--> Product
```

To order a selection of products, the customer goes to checkout page and uses a Fluid based Order form. All selected products are available in the fluid template as `{products}`.

The `OrderController->createAction` processes new Orders by creating OrderItems from the given Products.

Writing the code I'd like to have would look like this:

```php
class OrderController
{
    public function create(Order $order, array $products)
    {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $orderItem = new OrderItem()
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->setPrice($product->getPrice());
            $order->addOrderItem($orderItem);
        }
        $this->orderRepository->add($order);
    }
}
```

1. How to assign products to a Fluid form fields, in order to receive them as ControllerAction array argument?
2. How to trigger extbase to automagically provide an array of product objects to the ControllerAction?
3. I wonder if it is even possible to simplify the Controller createAction like shown below and assemble objects elsewhere:

```php
public function create(Order $order) {
    $this->orderRepository->add($order);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for the fluid template would be:

```
// basic form with the order as main object
<f:form action="create" object="{order}">
    // each order item with a product, using index to have no array with an empty index (Extbase does not like that)
    <f:for each="{products}" key="index" as="product">
        // Here you can set the product
        <f:form.hidden prpoerty="orderItems.{index}.product" value="{product} />
    </f:for>
</f:form>
```

This should be enough to use your single-line create action.
You can change the field type from select to whatever you want, but the `__identity` is mandatory to say Extbase which record it has to link.

When you want the orderItems to be new created, you need to remove the `__identity` field.

Comment: order.orderItems is empty for new orders, so nothing to iterate here.

Comment: Bingo, it works when using:
<f:for each="{products}" as="product" key="index">
    <f:form.hidden property="bookOrderItems.{index}.product" value="{product}" />
</f:for>

Comment: If you incorporate my changes into your answer, I will accept your answer

Comment: I thought there is only one product per item? Makes no sense if you use a `f:for each` view helper.

Comment: There is one product per item. There are n items per order. Given I have selected two products to order, my snippet will render as <input type="hidden" name="tx_myext_shop[order][items][0][product][__identity]" value="123" /><input type="hidden" name="tx_myext_shop[order][items][1][product][__identity]" value="456" />. In the Controller I get an Order with two new Item, each one with the proper relation to the given product